# Why keep the Precognitive badge on sites where no-one has or could have received it?

Tags: discussion, bug

Some sites (for example SO) have obviously been around for years, and therefore no-one was around to collect this badge as it didn't exist at the time.

I was therefore wondering why it still remains on SO, and therefore why it simply isn't just just removed from the site for which it has no relevance?

Comment: To annoy the hell out of those who are desperately hunting badges. Muwahahaha